# Is it possible to override enum base type in C using pragmas?

Tags: c, embedded

Is it possible to override enum base type in C using pragmas? What I know is that we can set compiler directives to set the enum base type as char, int, long. But is there any other method for setting an enum base type in the code for C language? For C++, I found pragmas like typedef enum : unsigned char can be used..but what is case for C?

Comment: Do you have some code to clarify what you mean?

Comment: Totally depends on the compiler, so you need to let us know what compiler you're using - or read it's manual.

Comment: `#pragma` means "do something in a compiler-specific way, or otherwise if you don't recognize the pragma, do nothing". So it doesn't make any sense at all to speak of pragmas without a specific compiler in mind.

Comment: I use diab compiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C language standard does not define what the various #pragma extensions do. Therefore there is no way to do this in conforming C.

If you have a specific compiler for which you need to do this, some specialised, embedded system targeting compilers do offer such functionality. You would be best off reading the documentation for that compiler for guidance on this.

However I would not reccomend instantiating an enum in embedded code at all, this offers little control as to the underlying type as you noticed and therefore is unpredictable for embedded code for which you presumably want to target some specific platform.

Instead, by all means define enumerated types, but instead of instanciating them just create variables of your chosen integral type and assign and compare them against the enum value literals.

Comment: Good advice about the dangers of enum, only use it where the size and signedness doesn't matter, like for example when defining an error result type to be returned from your functions. Note however that _enumeration constants_ (as opposed to enum variables) are guaranteed to have type `int`. So enums already have inconsistent behavior per definition of the C standard.